# How to get checkbox value and the value of the selected option of dropdown menu next to it

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I have a table , first 2 columns are a check box and a drop down menu. I want to get the value of the check box and of the selected item that is next to it and put it in an array. In essence what i want is something like this :

`[Object { name="blabla",  value="bla"} , Object {name='s1' value='3'}]`.

Where the first object is the check box and the second one is the drop down menu. I played around a bit with `.closest` but i can't seem to be able to chain them together.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vulkoingim/kuB67/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = [];
    $('#test').click(function () {
        $("#t tr").each(function () {
            $this = $(this)
            var $checkbox = $this.find("input:checkbox")
            var $select = $this.find("select[id^=s]");
            arr.push({
                name: $checkbox.attr('name'),
                value: $checkbox.val()
            });
            arr.push({
                name: $select.attr('id'),
                value: $select.val()
            });
        });
        console.log(arr);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuB67/7/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!With some modifications i managed to make it work as i want :)